# Finding members of sockets (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to find an efficient way to hash sockets created by socket.io. I'd like to make sure I'm not missing anything. Is there a list of socket members somewhere, or is there an easy way for me to look through the members (without having to run my node instance and create sockets just to iterate through them)?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the "without running my node instance" part. Do you want to list socket.io objects from outside the interpreter?

Comment: No, I'd like guidance on how to structure my code. In an IDE in another language (say, Visual Studio for C++), I'd be able to look through the members of the object. Of course, this doesn't make much sense in JavaScript in general as there are no guarantees to an object's member list. I'd just like to look through a listing of member variables that sockets have when they are created. I could do this by writing a quick script and test, but I would have zero explanation as to what the members were. Basically I'm looking for documentation on the class.

Comment: Try Komodo IDE. It is able to parse javascript objects as long as they're "properly" created via the prototype and a constructor (and sometimes even ad-hoc objects). Komodo does it by having a javascript interpreter built in (it's created using Mozilla webrunner so it's basically a modified Firefox) and the IDE compiles bits of your code as you type for syntax highlighting, auto-completion etc.